# Space for Null character in c strings

Tags: c

When is it necessary to explicitly provide space for a `NULL` character in C strings.
**For eg**;
This works without any error although I haven't declared `str` to be 7 characters long,i.e for the characters of string plus `NULL` character.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char str[6] = "string";
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Though in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/7652089 the user says
"*This is useful if you need to modify the string later on, but know that it will not exceed 40 characters (or 39 characters followed by a null terminator, depending on context).*"

What does it mean by "*depending on context*" ?

Comment: I guess in this context your str is an array of char so you can have the length for exemple with sizeof but if you pass you str to a function you'll get a char* and sizeof will give an other value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When is it necessary to explicitly provide space for a NULL character in C strings?

**Always**. Not having that `\0` character there will make functions like `strcpy`, `strlen` and printing via `%s` behave wrong. It might work for some examples (like your own) but I won't bet anything on that.

On the other hand, if your string is binary and you know the length of the packet you don't need that extra space. But then you cannot use `str*` functions. And this is not the case of your question, anyway.

Comment: Stumbling over here lately – *always* is not fully correct – if you know for whichever reasons how many bytes are in the string and limit reading it by other means (e.g. `send(theSocket, theBuffer, knownLengthOfUnterminated, 0); write(someFileDescriptor, theBuffer, knownLengthOfUnterminated);` or even `printf("%.7s", someFixedSizeString);`) *then* you don't *need* to. I'd agree, though, with not adding the null terminator still remaining potentially unsafe, some day someone might want to print debugging information or whatever else and fall into the trap...

Answer (score 2):

It is buggy, keyword "buffer overflow". The memory is overwritten.

```
char str[4] = "stringulation";
char str2[20];
printf("%s", str);
printf("%s", str2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour. You may think it works, but the code is broken.

To store a C string with 6 characters, and a null-terminator, you need a character array of length 7 or more.

> When is it necessary to explicitly provide space for a NULL character in C strings

There are no exceptions. A C string must always include a null terminating character.

---

> What does it mean by "depending on context"?

The answer there is drawing the distinction between a string variable that you intend to modify at a later time, or a string variable that you will not modify. In the former case, you may choose to allocate more than you need for the initial contents, because you want to be able to add more later. In the latter case, you can simply allocate as many characters are needed for the initial value, and no more.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to write on some address for which you have not requested may lead to data corruption, Random output or undefined nature of code.

Answer (score 0):

That 0 terminator<sup>1</sup> is how the various library functions ([`strcpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcpy.html), [`strlen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strlen.html), [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), etc.) identify the end of a string.  When you call a function like

```
char foo[6] = "hello";
printf( "%s\n", foo );
```

the array expression `foo` is converted to a pointer value before it's passed to the function, so all the function receives is the address of the first character; it doesn't know how long the `foo` array is.  So it needs some way to know where the end of the string is.  If `foo` didn't have that space for the 0 terminator, `printf()` would continue to print characters beyond the end of the array until it saw a 0-valued byte.

---

<sup>1. I prefer using the term "0 terminator" instead of "NULL terminator", just to avoid confusion with the NULL pointer, which is a different thing.</sup>

Comment: Actually, the term "NULL terminator" is incorrect, because `NULL`, by definition, is a pointer. The `'\0'` character is actually named "null", and is therefore the "null character". I think "terminating null character" or "string-terminating null character" express it best. Also, in a string context, saying "`'\0'` terminator" would be more precise than saying "0 terminator"