# Interesting behaviour when trying to copy parts of a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, memcpy

I have a string called buf and I want to copy the first 3 chars into a separate string and then the chars on position 4-6 into a separate string as well.

buf = "V01clsxxxxxxxxxx"

```
 char ID [3] = "";
 char CMD [3] = "";
 memcpy(ID, buf, 3*sizeof(char));
 memcpy(CMD, buf + 3, 3*sizeof(char));
```

When I output ID it says "V01" as expected.

When I output CMD it says "clsV01", when I would expect it to say "cls". I am a beginner in C and wonder where my error of thought lies and why this behaves like this?

I have solved the problem already by doing this

```
char * buff = (char*)buf;
char * ID  = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
char * CMD = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
memcpy(ID, buff, 3*sizeof(char));
memcpy(CMD, buff + 3, 3*sizeof(char));
```

But I would still like to know the underlying mechanism that causes it.

Best regards

Comment: You didn't show how you "output" your buffers. But probably you passed them to a function expecting a null-terminated string, and your buffers are not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Space for Null character in c strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054126/space-for-null-character-in-c-strings)

Comment: If you want a 3-character string you must have space for **4** elements. In C a string has a NUL terminator. If you don't provide that NUL terminator then the array is not a string, and you cannot use it with most of the string-handling library functions.

Comment: I output my buffers via a serial console. I am programming an arduino. I started to increase the sizes of the character arrays and depending on how high I go I get different artifacts. At [4] the output for CMD is "clsHV01" when I go to [8] CMD is "cls" but suddenly ID becomes "V01H"... I am confused.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is just a long-winded way to spell `1`. If  you are reasonably expecting a future plan to change the code to `wchar_t`, then these `sizeof(char)` expressions can serve as useful place holders, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is an UB. To store 3 chars strings you need **4** chars arrays.

Because you do not have room for the terminating zero. All the string considerartions do not make any sense as your datsa id not valid C string

so try:

```
 char ID [4] = "";
 char CMD [4] = "";
 memcpy(ID, buf, 3*sizeof(char));
 memcpy(CMD, buf + 3, 3*sizeof(char));
 ID[3] = 0;
 CMD[3] = 0;


char * ID  = malloc(4);
char * CMD = malloc(4);
memcpy(ID, buff, 3);
memcpy(CMD, buff + 3, 3);

 ID[3] = 0;
 CMD[3] = 0;
```

sizeof(char) is by definition always one.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for clarifying, another lesson learned. C is quite the daunting language :-)