# How to assign string of one variable to other variable?

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings, strcpy

This is my first question on this site.

How do i assign string of one variable to other variable. What am i doing wrong here?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main(){

char a[30],b[30];

scanf("%s",a);
b[30]=a[30];
printf("%s",b);

}
```

Comment: The short answer is to call `strcpy`, as the answers below are saying.  And that's a fine answer for today.  Soon, though, you're going to hear about pointers, and things are going to get confusing again.  At that point, you may want to read [this longer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734000/varying-string-variable-in-an-if-condition/48734567#48734567).

Answer (score 5):

Use the standard C function `strcpy` declared in the header `<string.h>`. For example

```
strcpy( b, a );
```

Arrays do not have the assignment operator.

As for your statement

```
b[30]=a[30];
```

then `b[30]` and `a[30]` are undefined objects of the type char that are beyond the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main(){

char a[30],b[30];

scanf("%s", a);
strcpy(b, a);          //header file <string.h>
                       //strcpy(destination, source)
printf("%s",b);

}
```

The strcpy() function will copy the content of string a in string b.