# Assigning a char pointer to string literal generated at runtime - Is this dynamic allocation?

Tags: c, cvi

I am in the process of reviewing some code that someone else wrote. I came across an interesting case involving strings within this code and I need help understanding how this works.

There is a function designed to be exported to a DLL. At the top of the function, we have this declaration

```
char *msg; // pointer to char
int error = 0; //my error code
```

Then, later in the code, we invoke a special library function for the IDE we use:

```
if(error < 0)
msg = getErrorString(error);
```

This inbuilt library function (getErrorString) expects you to provide a pointer to char where it can store the generated error string at runtime.

Finally, the code author calls the below:

```
free(msg); // freeing dynamically allocated memory??
```

So, I guess there is memory allocated dynamically at runtime which is large enough to store the generated error string? How is this allowed without explicitly calling something like malloc? If I were writing equivalent code, my first instinct would be to declare some static array like msg[256] and then do something like:

```
char msg[256] = {""};
sprintf(msg, "%s", getErrorString(error));
```

So my main question is, how can you declare a pointer to char, then assign it to a string which is generated at runtime, as shown in the original code? It seems that memory is being dynamically allocated at runtime, perhaps by the runtime engine. Is this what's happening with this code? Is my static array method preferred in this case?

Comment: Getertrorstring called malloc

Comment: "This inbuilt library function (getErrorString) expects you to provide a pointer to char where it can store the generated error string at runtime." No, it does not — or at least, your example certainly doesn't show you *providing* such a pointer. It looks like `getErrorString` does indeed perform its own dynamic memory allocation using `malloc` or the equivalent.  In that case, it's sensible and appropriate for the caller to later call `free(msg)`.

Comment: @SteveSummit msg = getErrorString(error);
Isn't that providing the pointer?

Comment: @RealTime-OS No, `msg` is a pointer variable which *receives* the pointer value returned by the call to `getErrorString`.  (And a good thing, too, because prior to that, `msg` was an uninitialized pointer, pointing nowhere.)

Comment: I think you get the gist of what I originally stated. (I "provide" the pointer, my pointer "recieves" the value etc...)

Comment: I suggest removing the word "literal" from the question title.

Comment: @SupportUkraine `sprintf(msg, "%s", getErrorString(error));` The root cause of this leak was created by the bad API design, not by the caller.

Comment: @RealTime-OS Sorry, but I think it is you who are not getting the gist.  You "provided" a pointer *variable*.  You did **not** provide a pointer *value*.  The pointer *value* came from `getErrorString`.

Comment: @SteveSummit I never said I provide a pointer "value", so you are clearly confused

Comment: @SupportUkraine [The `strdup` function is in the latest C Standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup).

Comment: @RealTime-OS I guess you had better ignore my answer, then, and now I'm sorry I wasted my time composing it.

Comment: @RealTime-OS Btw given your user name, please note that dynamic allocation is deeply problematic in embedded systems for a long list of reasons. If you are making a DLL for some PC program, then it's fine to use though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is this allowed without explicitly calling something like malloc?

Well, it is almost certainly the case that somewhere within the implementation of the `getErrorString`, there *is* a call to `malloc` or the equivalent.

It is likely that the implementation of `getErrorString` looks something like this:

```
char *getErrorString(int error)
{
    char *ret = malloc(25);
    if(ret == NULL) abort();
    switch(error) {
        case EMUCHMEM:
            strcpy(ret, "too much memory");
            break;

        case EIUNDERFLOW:
            strcpy(ret, "integer underflow");
            break;

        case EDIVBY1:
            strcpy(ret, "divide by 1");
            break;

        default:
            sprintf(ret, "error %d", error);
            break;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

> If I were writing equivalent code, my first instinct would be to declare some static array like msg[256] and then do something like:
> `char msg[256] = {""};`
> `sprintf(msg, "%s", getErrorString(error));`

That doesn't make much sense.  It represents unnecessary extra memory (256 bytes in `msg[]`) and unnecessary extra copying (by `sprintf`).

> So my main question is, how can you declare a pointer to char, then assign it to a string which is generated at runtime, as shown in the original code?

You can *always* declare a pointer to `char`, then assign to it a string which is generated at runtime.

This can be a confusing point, though.  You may have heard that strings are represented as arrays of `char` in C — which is true — and you may also have heard that you can't assign arrays in C — which is also true.  You may have heard that instead of directly assigning strings, you always have to call `strcpy`.  But that's *not* necessarily true — you can also "assign" strings by simply assigning pointers, which is what's going on when you say `msg = getErrorString(error)`.  In other words, there are two completely different ways of assigning strings in C: by copying arrays, or assigning pointers.  See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734000/varying-string-variable-in-an-if-condition/48734567#48734567) for more on this point.

> It seems that memory is being dynamically allocated at runtime

Yes, that's how it seems.

> Is my static array method preferred in this case?

As other comments have suggested, dynamic memory allocation *in this case* may or may not be a good idea.  As a general rule, though, dynamic memory allocation is a perfectly fine — more or less vital — technique.  Static memory allocation, on the other hand, can have plenty of problems of its own.

Comment: A sound implementation would rather use a LUT and return a `const char*` pointing into an array of strings, where the enum is used as index (optionally with a defensive bounds-check). Faster, safer and overall more sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you've described, `getErrorString` is clearly calling `malloc` or `calloc` (or some equivalent) itself and returning that pointer.  This is actually fairly common practice - see the POSIX [`strdup`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) function as another example.

The catch is that *you* are responsible for deallocating that memory when you're done with it.  If `getErrorString` allocates memory dynamically then that needs to be documented so anyone using it will know to `free` that memory when they're done with it.

> If I were writing equivalent code, my first instinct would be to declare some static array like msg[256] and then do something like:
>
> `char msg[256] = {""};
> sprintf(msg, "%s", getErrorString(error));`

Bad idea, since you discard the pointer value returned by `getErrorString`, meaning you can never `free` the memory that it allocated.

`getErrorString` is allocating all the necessary memory to store the string for you under the hood; you don't need to set aside your own buffer to store the string itself.  You only need to store the returned pointer value so you can `free` that memory later.

---

How to handle dynamically allocated memory has been a thorny problem for APIs since forever.  *In general* the ideal design has the entity responsible for memory allocation also be responsible for deallocation; personally, I would have designed `getErrorString` to receive the error code *and* a pointer to the target buffer and its size:

```
char *getErrorString( int errorCode, char *buf, size_t bufSize )
{
  switch( errorCode )
  {
    case SOME_ERROR:
      strncpy( buf, "Error message for SOME_ERROR", bufSize );
      break;

    case SOME_OTHER_ERROR:
      strncpy( buf, "Error message for SOME_OTHER_ERROR", bufSize );
      break;

    ...
  }
  /**
   * Make sure buf is properly 0-terminated, since strncpy won't
   * zero-terminate if the target buffer is shorter than the
   * source string
   */
  buf[bufSize-1] = 0;
  return buf;
}
```

That way *I* am responsible for both the allocation and deallocation of the buffer.  I can use an `auto` array and not have to worry about memory management at all:

```
void foo( void )
{
  char msg[81];
  ...
  fprintf( stderr, "%s", getErrorString( error, msg, sizeof msg ) );
  ...
}
```

In this case the error message is being written to `msg`; `getErrorString` returns the address of `msg` so it can be called as part of `fprintf`; and since it's an `auto` variable, the memory for `msg` will automatically be deallocated at function exit.

Alternately, I can dynamically allocate that memory if I wish:

```
char *msg = calloc( 81, sizeof *msg );
...
fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", getErrorString( error, msg, 81 );
...
free( msg );
```

But either way the responsibility for allocating and deallocating memory is in the same entity (the code calling `getErrorString`); it's not being split between two different entities.

---

Another option is for a function to maintain a static internal buffer:

```
char *getErrorString( int error )
{
  static char buf[SOME_SIZE+1]; // where SOME_SIZE is the length of the longest
                                // error string

  switch( error )
  {
    case SOME_ERROR: 
      strcpy( buf, "Error string for SOME_ERROR" );
      break;

     case SOME_OTHER_ERROR:
       strcpy( buf, "Error string for SOME_OTHER_ERROR" );
       break;
   
      ...
  }
  return buf;
}
```

Since `buf` is declared `static` its lifetime is the lifetime of the entire program, so it doesn't go away when `getErrorString` exits.  This way nobody has to worry about managing memory for the buffer.

The problem with this approach is that `getErrorString` is no longer re-entrant or thread-safe - you only have that single buffer over the entire program, so if `getErrorString` is interrupted by other code that itself calls `getErrorString`, or if two threads call `getErrorString` simultaneously, then that buffer is going to be corrupted.

---

As a final alternative, if all the strings are constant, then there's no need to set aside any memory *at all* - just return the string literal directly:

```
/**
 * Attempting to modify a string literal invokes undefined behavior,
 * so we don't want this pointer to be used as the target of
 * a strcpy or sprintf call.  We change the return value to const char *
 * so the compiler will yell at us if we try to modify the pointed-to
 * string.  
 */
const char *getErrorString( int error )
{
  switch( error )
  {
    case SOME_ERROR:
      return "Error string for SOME_ERROR";
      break;

    case SOME_OTHER_ERROR:
      return "Error string for SOME_OTHER_ERROR";
      break;
    
    ...
  }
  return "Unknown error code";
}
```

Now we can just call the function directly and not worry about it:

```
fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", getErrorString( error ) );
```

If you still want to set aside memory to store the error string for whatever reason you can:

```
const char *str = getErrorString( error );
char *buf = malloc( strlen( str ) + 1 );
if ( buf )
  strcpy( buf, str );
```

or

```
char *buf = strdup( getErrorString( error ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

`getErrorString` must documents that it calls `malloc`. It's generally considered very bad practice to write an API where functions return pointers to allocated memory and then expect someone else to clean it up. We know from 40 years of C history that badly designed APIs like this is exactly how you create memory leaks all over the place.

A better API would provide an explicit init/create function and an explicit cleanup/delete function. What those functions do internally is none of the caller's business - they just need to ensure to call init before anything else and cleanup the last thing they do.

On the topic of s****y API design, I would expect a function `getErrorString` to return a `const char*`, because why would an error message need to be modified by the caller? This ought to be an immutable string.

Comment: Your opinions about good and bad API design do not answer the OP's question.

Comment: @SteveSummit The question was if dynamic allocation happens in this program during run-time and I answered that. Basically read the documentation of `getErrorString` or how else can you tell.