# can you simply just reassign a new string to a pointer without any issues?

Tags: c, pointers, scope, c-strings, strtok

I refer to the sample code provided below from  IBM's website regarding the use of Strtok, however the function of Strtok is not my main concern.

My concern is the reuse of char pointers or strings inside the loop, in particular, the string variable named "token" in the code below.

I have read many articles already, but none of them answer this question to me in "black and white".

I'd like to clarify, if the laws of C allow the reuse of char or string array pointer variables like this in order to avoid dangerous coding.

As you can see, the variable "token" is reused over and over again in the loop, and the contents that the pointer representing each time is changed and reassigned with different sized strings each time - this is of course the produced tokens.

Can you use pointers in this way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main(void)
{
   char *token, *string = "a string, of, ,tokens\0,after null terminator";
 
   /* the string pointed to by string is broken up into the tokens
      "a string", " of", " ", and "tokens" ; the null terminator (\0)
      is encountered and execution stops after the token "tokens"     */
   token = strtok(string, ",");
   do
   {
      printf("token: %s\n", token);
   }
   while (token = strtok(NULL, ","));
}
 
/*****************  Output should be similar to:  *****************
 
token: a string
token:  of
token:
token: tokens
*/
```

Although this is an example, my main project that I'm trying to write, requires a string variable of some kind, in order to store and handle strings which will be - incoming commands from a telecommunications modem.  Commands like this will be of variable lengths each time, and the variable would be named something like "incoming_received_SMS_message", and this will be used in a loop so that the rest of the code determine the command and run the appropriate functions.

So instead of using malloc, memset or going to far with things as some suggest, can you simply just reassign a new string to a pointer without any issues? (By the way I am fully aware that a pointer only contains an address).

---

EDIT:

So I've tried this code in Arduino IDE to test the theory, but it still generates errors;

```
char * pointer;
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {

pointer = "sample text";
pointer = "even more sample text";

Serial.println(pointer);

}
```

But Then this generates the following errors;

warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
pointer = "sample text";

warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
pointer = "even more sample text";

Comment: You can't `strtok` a string literal. It is read-only.

Comment: There is no "new string" here - `strtok` modifies the string that is passed in as first argument and returns a pointer to a part of it (or a null pointer)

Comment: Reusing a pointer variable is not inherently "dangerous" — it's just like reusing any other variable.  For example, if you have an integer variable `i` that's used over and over again, or for multiple different things, that's not "dangerous" — although depending on your preferred programming style you might call it confusing.

Comment: What you *do* have to be careful about — and this will be of concern to you in your comms-handling code — is the *allocation* of the data to which your pointer variables point.

Comment: Don't confuse *pointers* with *the things they point to*! There are basically no relevant rules about pointers, except for only dereferencing them when they point to something. As long as you follow that rule, you can do whatever you want. The confusion comes when you think about managing the things you are trying to point to, e.g. with malloc and free

Comment: Did they teach you about memory addresses? They are just numbers, and pointers are just variables that hold numbers. The only reason you have to write `char *` instead of `int` is so the *compiler* knows what it points to. Not the CPU! The CPU doesn't need to know it's a char*.

Comment: *can you simply just reassign a new string to a pointer without any issues?* A more accurate statement, I think, would be that you can simply just reassign a new pointer to a string without any issues.  But, yes, the point is that you can *certainly* sling pointers around like this, and once you know what you're doing, it is generally easier and vastly more efficient than "using malloc, memset or going too far with things as some suggest".

Comment: You might find [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734000) and its answers useful.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the provided code has undefined behavior because the function strtok tries to change a string literal

```
char *token, *string = "a string, of, ,tokens\0,after null terminator";
token = strtok(string, ",");
```

any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

It seems you mean a character array initialized by a string literal instead of a pointer to the string literal itself

```
char *token, string[] = "a string, of, ,tokens\0,after null terminator";
token = strtok(string, ",");
```

A pointer may be reassigned as any non-constant variable. For example you may write

```
int x = 0;
x = 10;
x = 20;
```

The same way you may reassigned a pointer like for example

```
char *s = "Hello";

s = "World!";
s = "Bye!";
```

Or another example

```
char s[] = "Hello";
char *p;

for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
{
    p = s + i;
    putchar( *p );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Pay attention to that if a pointer will point to an object that is not already alive then the pointer will be invalid and dereferencing such a pointer invokes undefined behavior. For example

```
char *p;

{
    char s[] = "Hello";
    p = s;
}

puts( p ); // undefined behavior!
```

Comment: Okay,  so lets say that I continued to use a pointer like this to store some new strings


```
char *s = "Hello";

s = "World!";
s = "Bye!";
s = "again!";
s = "again!";
s = "again!";
s = "again!";
s = "again!";
s = "again!";
s = "again!";
s = "you get the idea.....";
```

No matter how many times this variable was changed, would this be safe?
Also, what happends to the data it was originally pointing to? is this erased automatically
or will it eventually start causing memory leaks? does the old text in the string have to be deleted first? or is this automatic?

Comment: @Tyranus There's no reason it would not be safe. `s` just holds a number which is the memory address of those string literals. String literals (`"Hello")` tell the compiler to put that string *somewhere in the program file*. And then `s = "Hello";` puts the address of where the compiler put it, into the variable `s`. It literally just does `s=12345` if the compiler used address 12345.

Comment: @Tyranus You need to free only what you allocated with malloc, calloc or realloc. On your comment the pointer points to string literals that have static storage duration. Such a code is safe and valid.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, user253751, That was a bad example of code that I have included. So another issue is that I'm trying to weigh up using strings or stick with char (pointers), I think some of you are indicating that strings are incompatible with strtok function, and only char type? if So, would this would be okay to use with a char pointer type, and not the string? Unless you believe strings are better to work with?
I only ask as above you warned that "any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior."  By String literal do you mean a String type or Char type?

Comment: @Tyranus "Hello" - this is a string literal. char ([ = "Hello"; - this is a pointer to a string literal.

Comment: Hi all, thankyou for your responses yesterday, however I've tried this theory in the Arduino IDE compiler.  I've added this to my post above, but i'm still getting errors.
warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
 pointer = "even more sample text";

Please see above

char * pointer;
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {

pointer = "sample text";
pointer = "even more sample text";

Serial.println(pointer);

}

Comment: @Tyranus In C++ opposite to C string literals have types of constant character arrays.  So in C++ you have to write const char *pointer = "sample text"; Also in C it is a good idea to declare pointers to string literals with the qualifier const.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, so what If I wanted to change the contents of the string value?, are you saying this is not possible?

Comment: @Tyranus You may not change the content of a string literal. But you may change the content of a character array initialized by a string literal. For example you may not write char *p = "hello"; p[0] = 'H'; But you may write char s[] = "hello"; s[0] = 'H';

Comment: And then change each index via a loop?

Comment: @Tyranus It depends on whether you need that.

Comment: Well the use of the variable would be to store received SMS messages from a serial based cellular telecommunications modem. So the main code needs a variable it can store strings in each of a different size each time, up to 255 characters each.  Eg.   message = get_next_msg();