# C, convert an char argv[] argument to char[] makes gibberish

Tags: c

I am trying a C program and a part of it is taking file names as arguments, but when I try to convert them from the argument `char *argv[]` to `char fPath[1000]` to come out to gibberish.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char fPath[1000];
    char uinp[1000];

    // Check for arguments
    if( argc == 2 ) {
        printf("The argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
    } else if ( argc > 1 ) {
        printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    // Set argv as the file for editing if it is set
    if (argv[1] != NULL) {
    
        printf("argv set = %s", argv[1]);
        char fPath = *argv[1]; <-- This appears to be where the Issues is.
    
    } else {

        printf("File: ");
        scanf("%s", fPath);

    }
```

After that it makes a file that is supposed to be the name of the argument given but instead it makes one named like "`M'$'\026''b'$'\374\177`" but in the program the you can only see the `b`.

Comment: You declared a second `fPath` variable at `char fPath = *argv[1];` which goes out of scope at the following `}`.  The first `fPath` is still uninitializd.  You presumably meant to use `strcpy(fPath, argv[1]);` — but you should worry about the `else` clause too and about buffer overflows.  If you compile with GCC, use `-Wshadow` (as well as other options, such as `-Werror -Wall -Wextra`) to have the compiler tell you about such problems.

Comment: This is a case where you can, and in my opinion should, not need to use `strcpy` at all.  You can say `char *fPath;`, and then `fPath = argv[1];`.  Among other things, that way you don't need to worry about whether 1000 characters is enough or not.

Comment: @SteveSummit maybe he wants to modify `fPath` without modifying the `argv[1]`

Comment: @0___________ More importantly, my suggestion would totally break the `scanf` call in the `else` clause, which I read and replied too quickly to notice.

Comment: @VaD_3r One of the hard things to learn about C strings at first is that there are sort of two completely separate ways of handling them.  In your original code, you're sort of using one way in the first half of your `if` statement, and the other way in the `else` clause.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734000/varying-string-variable-in-an-if-condition/48734567#48734567) for some more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char fPath = *argv[1]; <-- This appears to be where the Issues is.
```

You declare another variable `fPath` having type `char` and assigning the first letter of the second element of the `argv`. This fPath ends its life when the `if` completes.

Basically the whole if makes no sense and the code in `else` invokes undefined behaviour as `fPath` is not initialized.

You need to copy the string.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char fPath[1000];
    char uinp[1000];

    // Check for arguments
    if( argc == 2 ) 
    {
        // Set argv as the file for editing if it is set
        if (argv[1] != NULL) 
        {
            printf("argv set = %s\n", argv[1]);
            strcpy(fPath, argv[1]);
    
            printf("File: ");
            scanf("%s\n", fPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica honestly I did not even read that part.

Comment: Fair enough.  I did not notice OP's was the source of that part of code.

Comment: @0___________: Good reply to a really stupid question.  There were just SOOOO many thing wrong with the OP's code.  Starting with the "shadowing", continuing through "undefined behavior", and the fact that there WAS NO GOOD REASON for any of that nonsense!

Comment: @FoggyDay Guy i literally do not know C or anything.