# Which is generally better to represent strings in C ? an array of char or by using a pointer to a char ? and why?

Tags: c

How would someone represent strings in C, knowing that in an array of char, I kind of need to know ahead of time how many characters the array may hold, and if I were to change the string in the same variable, it will cause a problem. So would a pointer to a char always be better ?

Comment: please edit the question and provide a [mcve] example

Comment: If the array of char has an initializer, you can omit the length and let the compiler set it automatically. For example `char test[] = "12345";` is the same as `char test[6] = "12345";` because the string literal initializer has 6 `char`s including the null terminator. This applies to arrays in general, omitting the length from the definition will set the length to one plus the maximum index of the initialized elements.

Comment: *"So would a pointer to a char always be better?"* No, for the reason you stated - you might want to change the text of a string literal pointed to. You choose the appropriate method. If you want to chnage the length of an array you can use `malloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: Both are used.  You should be equally comfortable using either approach — and you should always know which way you're using.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734000#48734567).

Comment: Strings are always null terminated arrays of `char` in C; even string literals are represented as arrays of `char`. Note that attempted modification of a string literal causes undefined behavior. Arrays decay to pointers in most expressions, so you end up working with pointers a lot.

Comment: It turns out you can't *not* use pointers to refer to strings.  Even though C strings are always arrays, in C all array references automatically "decay" into pointer references, so you always end up accessing strings using pointers (whether you realize it or not).  That's why functions like `strlen` and `strcpy` accept parameters of type `char *`.  But for any string you're working with, it's important to remember whether it is or might be (a) a string literal, (b) an array you've declared, or (c) some `malloc`'ed memory you've allocated.  Those things determine what actions are possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the main differences :

1. If you use a pointer to a char, you have two choices :

```c
char *s; // You need to allocate memory to this later, at runtime. 
char *s = "Hello World"; // This is a read-only string. You cannot change this later.
```

2. If you use a array of char, you need to define a strict length.

```c
char c[10]; // Define a buffer of max 10 chars. If last char is \0, it's a c string.
```

So, If you want a read-only string, use the read-only pointer to char.

If you want a strict length, use a char array.

If you want to allocate memory at runtime, use a pointer to char.